# ¿Cómo puedo obtener mediante SELECT el tiempo extra de trabajo en MYSQL?

Tags: mysql

Por ejemplo: si mi hora de salida es a las 6:00 PM y salí a las 6:10 PM, quiero obtener esos 10 minutos de tiempo extra, para después sumar todo el tiempo extra de toda la semana.

Esta es mi tabla en MySQL:

```
`Horarios
idHorario int
fecha date
día varchar
entrada time
salida time
`
```

Gracias de antemano!!

Comment: Podrias poner lo que haz intentado? Ya que hay varios factores, primero deberias de obtner cual sera la hora de salida y de ahi hacer un tipo de datediff para obtener la diferencia de tiempos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes utilizar el TIMESTAMPDIFF

```
SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND,'2021-03-25 12:01:01','2021-03-25 10:02:00');
```